# How to block the flow, but keep the GUI responsive

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a method which updates a richtextbox when it executes. I have to call this method a few times, without blocking the GUI. Once a call ended and the richtextbox populated, i have to block the flow to show some info to the user ( the next calls to the method should not start ). I have done this with a MessageBox.Show().

Here appears another problem, i have to be able to abort the program at any given time but the modal messagebox doesn't let me do that. Maybe you will tell me to get another form and simulate the messagebox, but hey, i still need to block the flow if the modal box will be replaced.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean. What do you mean when you say "block the flow"?

Comment: i have to call that method 10 times. after the first call let's say, the second should not start until i say so. The MessageBox did that corectly but , also that MessageBox doesn't let me click abort.

Comment: Is this a multi-threading question?

Comment: The method i call is time consuming and i don't want the GUI to be unresponsive, so i think yes, is a multi threading question. Tell me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a multi-threading issue. There are many ways you can achieve this.  Here is an explanation of what multi-threading is.  [What is multi-threading?](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/M/multithreading.html)

Also, here's my favorite tutorial on multi-threading: [albahari.com](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Threads have their own stack and operate independently.  Here's one example of how to spawn a thread:

```
Thread _thread = new Thread(() => { MessageBox.Show("Hello world!", "Spawned in a different thread"); });

_thread.Start();
```

To invoke your richtextbox from another thread, one way to do it is to create a method inside of your form that appends text to your textbox by invoking it.  Here is an example of how to do it:

```
public void AddText(string Text)
{
    if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {   
       SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(AddText); // Delegate
       this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
    }
    else { this.textBox1.AppendText(text); }
}
```

Here is a msdn reference to what you're trying to do:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx

Comment: Please don't post version-specific links to MSDN articles unless the answer is version-specific.